# Is it possible to securely enforce that a user can only access data through a relation?

Tags: google-app-maker

I've been reading through all of the AppMaker documentation on security but there's one part that I can't wrap my head around which is how you limit access to only subsets of records.

Let's say I'm the **Manager** of a company and I want access to see **Contract** records for each **Employee** that I manage. I should have access to the **Contract** records that correspond to people I manage but not to those in other teams. I do need to have access to some contacts but not to all of them.

I can't seem to see how to do this in the interface. I had expected that it might be the case of creating a new Datasource which was filtered to only include the relevant records and setting access permissions on the new  Datasource but Datasources don't seem to have any permissions assignable to them.

Is it possible to create access controls that limit access to subsets of data (from the server) or do you have to rely on hiding it in the client?

Comment: On your server, you have something called filters. So while querying for data source from your Tables, you should provide appropriate filters. This will return only those much data which matched the filter criteria.

Comment: Hi @DarpanSanghavi could you expand on that and also how that ensures that nothing else can be accessed. Thank you

Comment: Please refer [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources) once. Refer 'Query script ' section.

Comment: If you are talking about DB level security then refer [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-app-data#secure_operations_on_records)

Comment: Darpan I don't think any of your pointers actually answer the question. The problem is not how you filter results but how you lock down the ability to access the unfiltered results. The seucrity section of the documentation does not answer that question on how to make only subsets of records available to different users

Comment: I don't think that you have taken enough care to read the full docs from my pointers. It is clearly mentioned that 'You need to write server side scripts to handle this logic'. By default DB level security will work for a particular set of roles. For individual record security you need to write server side scripts, which is nothing but filters.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some assumptions in regards to your data setup, but here is my best attempt at answering your question. Most likely the Model Security setup should help you accomplish what you want to do, however to set this up you need to use the 'Advanced' option under model security. For your Contracts model set the 'Load' option to 'Owner or Roles', the field option you would need to choose is 'Advanced' and that will give you the option to set your field email to related models email field option. For this to work your Manager model needs to have a 'Manager Email' field.

Assumptions made:

1. 3 models, Managers, Employees, and Contracts.
2. Managers model has an email field and Employees model has an email field.
3. Relations are as follows: Managers(one) - Employees(many) and Employees(one) - Contracts(many).

See the attached screenshots:
[image: Model Field Advanced Option]

[image: Model Security for relations]

Comment: this makes sense but I think is the challenge - to secure access to any particular row you need the email of the person with access to be on that row. Which sadly doesn't work for a lot of scenarios

Comment: @PeterNixey I suppose if you could explain a little more about your particular scenario, then maybe I am able to expand on this some more. Specifically, what kind of field do you use that would identify which employee belongs to which manager, or how do you determine the current manager if not by email? Generally app maker uses emails do determine the current user. Are you using the Directory and determining managers through the Directory?